# Adding a variable into the path of an image

Tags: python, tkinter, path, decode

I am trying to make my client program show an image with a name corresponding to the message received from a server.

So if the client receives b'red' it should display the image on the path: "/home/pi/Desktop/gifs/red.gif"

Here is the code for the client program:

```
import socket
import tkinter as tk
HOST = 'localhost'    # The remote host
PORT = 50007              # The same port as used by the server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))

message = s.recv(1024)
print(message) # Message is a bytes-like-object e.g. b'red'

root = tk.Tk()
image1 = tk.PhotoImage(file="/home/pi/Desktop/gifs/x.gif") 
#x should change accordingly to the received message 
Thelabel = tk.Label(image=image1)
Thelabel.pack()
root.update()
```

How do I make a variable in the path to my image which takes the information in message? So I guess the bytes-like-object has to be decoded into a string?

Comment: [Why not just decode and format byte-string?](https://ideone.com/wkC6lQ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @CommonSense comment to the question.

```
    byte_string = s.recv(1024)
    path = '/home/pi/Desktop/gifs/%s.gif' % byte_string.decode()

    root = tk.Tk()
    image1 = tk.PhotoImage(file=path) 
    Thelabel = tk.Label(image=image1)
    Thelabel.pack()
    root.update()
```